# How are the levels calculated?

Tags: miitomo

There are two kinds of level in Miitomo:

- Popularity Level, which seems to evolve depending on your interactions with your friends.
- Fashion Level, which seems to evolve when you change your clothes.

What exactly makes those levels go up? From my own experience, it seems like the Popularity Level is going up when you receive likes and comments on your questions. For the Fashion Level, it seems like it did go up each time I bought new clothes in the shop and equipped them, but also when I did something as simple as removing a hat. What are the actions needed for each level category ? Is there an amount of points won for each one of those, and is there a daily limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all that's been confirmed so far:

•POPULARITY•
-get hearts on your answers

-get comments on your answers

-get hearts on your miifotos

-get comments on your miifotos

•STYLE•

-change your current clothes [ONCE PER DAY]

-check put the shop [ONCE PER DAY]

-share a miifoto [ONCE PER DAY]

-get comments on your miifotos

-get hearts on your miifotos

-change outfits (as pointed out by ChronoD)

It also seems that buying new clothes on the shop, or earning them as prizes on the Drop minigame has varying effects on the style bar, as for me I've managed to level up from trying new clothes even after the once per day thing (or at least I think so) but sometimes it just doesn't change at all, perhaps buying them does not increase it (as is Jeremy Avalon's case) but earning them does.
As for the popularity points, it may be limited to a specific amount per day (or maybe my answers aren't worthy enough of other people's hearts and comments ;-;) also, adding friends could have an effect on the popularity level, has anyone tested that? As for me I have over 70 friends by adding random strangers and I'm on popularity level 7 but I've been there for a while.

Also, I've tried what ChronoD said he would try yesterday, my results were:
I started at level 6 with no extra points, did all of the pnce per day stuff and the war was at about 3/4 changing clothes or outfits had no effect.

Comment: Oh, it seems then that there is a lot more than just changing the outfit then. Are you 100% affirmative for the other one, like checking the shop or sharing a miifoto once a day ?

Comment: I can assure you that checking the shop does in fact add style points, as for the miifoto, various sources claim it does, yet I havent tried myself, but knowing nintendo, it probably does

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing. I will put conclusions first, then my process second.

---

Conclusions:

Popularity increases when anyone else likes or comments on your posts. There doesn't appear to be a maximum on this.

Style goes up whenever you change clothes to a new combination. There doesn't appear to be a maximum on this.

---

Testing Process:

**Popularity**

I had one friend like as many of my posts as he could and comment on them as well. After a lot of actions, my popularity still appeared to increase. I had a second friend do the same, with the same effect.

NOTES: It's difficult to tell precisely the effect since there seems to be a delay in the update. After all, the friend has to like it, it has to connect to the internet and save the information, then you have to receive the information and it has to adjust accordingly. It seemed to update in batches with up to an hour delay.

**Style**

I used 3 specific outfits that were already preset. I cycled through them continuously. My style went up to a certain level. I cycled through them a few more rounds. My style was at the same level. Therefore, cycling doesn't seem to have an affect after a certain point. I tried two more outfits, once each. Style went up. I tried to cycle them, Style did not change. Therefore, it appears to be a one time effect. I took those outfits and removed parts. Using one outfit (consisting of a hat, bowtie, shirt, and pants), I used all combinations of those 4 objects (16 in total). Each one APPEARED to have an effect on style, although the change was small and difficult to know for certain. My overall style level did increase during those 16 versions, so some increase must have happened.

At this point, I had used 20 unique outfits and it still appeared to increase, suggesting that there is no maximum, or that it is at least higher than 20.

I haven't been able to test over multiple days, but it seems like it should reset since I've only been using 3 outfits regularly and still had a decent style level.

---

Hopefully this helps you out some. Let me know if you find any contradictory data and I'll see if I can do some additional testing.

Comment: I just purchased a Gothic Lolita dress in the shop and auto-equipped it but did not gain any Style points (including after several reloads of the app). I've already changed clothes at least once today, and currently I'm at Style Level 8 (Genius Stylist) with no additional points.

Comment: Interesting. I'll do some more testing tomorrow when (I think) it should reset and see if it has anything to do with outfit types. All of my current outfits have different combinations, so that might affect it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't use the outfits feature and have gained all my style points through individual item changes. Don't know if that's helpful.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get to the next style level and then wait a day and see how many outfits changes it takes to hit the level after it. If anyone else wants to do that too it would help with the data immensely.

Comment: So I've been trying to get more data but there is so much lag between changing things and the points appearing that it's hard to tell. I did the big run of style changes again but didn't get as many levels (due to scaling). But it seems like my initial was incorrect. It was just due to lag. It seems to have stopped somewhere before 10